# Time Zone with Ajax

Tags: ajax

I have this Code in ajax which automatically pulls country and related state & city from js file.

I want to add Time-Zone to the related country/state/city.

Is there any better alternative way to get time-zone of the user performing sign-up?

Following is the code, Thanks

```
 <select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">
     <option value="">Select Country</option>
 </select>
 <select name="state" class="states" id="stateId">
     <option value="">Select State</option>
 </select>
 <select name="city" class="cities" id="cityId">
     <option value="">Select City</option>
 </select>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://lab.iamrohit.in/js/location.js"></script>
```

Comment: is `location.js` a external file or written by you guys?

Comment: Hi Reddy, I found this on following link: http://www.iamrohit.in/countries-states-and-cities-database-of-world-in-mysql/

Comment: I think it's written by this guy

Comment: OK so possibly you can try finding a different plugin which has time zone, Else write your jquery function to give you time zone when you pass a country name. For this you must spend some time gathering all the country names and its time zone.

Comment: was hoping to find script like the one in code

Comment: This http://www.maxmind.com/timezone.txt will give a a csv fiel with all country and timezone, May be you can use this data.